# Logback JNDI Connection Source

Tags: java, logging, jndi, logback, appender

Logback allows you to define an `DBAppender` with a JNDI data source like so:

```
<connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.JNDIConnectionSource">
    <jndiLocation>java:comp/env/jdbc/dbLogging</jndiLocation>
</connectionSource>
```

I will be deploying this Java app as a WAR to Tomcat, **but want DB logging to work when I'm testing locally in Eclipse or in a standalone Tomcat instance**. Where/how do I configure the JNDI data source that Logback will use when it reads the above configuration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a standalone tomcat instance you would configure `server.xml` or `context.xml` in tomcat to define the data source as per normal (see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html))

For using it locally in Eclipse, i.e. without a Web container, you'd change your `connectionSource` to something like:

```
<connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
  <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
  <url>jdbc:mysql://host_name:3306/datebase_name</url>
  <user>username</user>
  <password>password</password>
</connectionSource>
```

See also, [logback manual on appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) which has a tomcat example.

Comment: Thanks @beny23 (+1) - can you be a little more specific about the `connectionSource` in Eclipse? Is this a Project Property? A command-line argument to Eclipse itself? Can you provide an example? Thanks again!

Comment: For eclipse you would have a different log back config file